# Mono: How to execute a shell script in a blocking manner?

Tags: linux, bash, mono

I am trying to call a bash script from Mono. Because the script in turn calls "pico2wave" (the Linux implementation of Android's Pico TTS voice), the call to the script must block the execution of the Mono code.

I could of course modify the script to touch/rm a file working as a lock, but is there a way to accomplish this task in Mono code?

Thanks for any advice,

Carsten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Process.WaitForExit` to wait (block) till your script has finished executing.

[Process.WaitForExit Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Sets the period of time to wait for the associated process to exit, 
>   and blocks the current thread of execution until the time has elapsed 
>   or the process has exited. To avoid blocking the current thread, use
>   the Exited event.

Example shell script that sleeps for 5 seconds and then exits, named `shell-block.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5
exit 0
```

Example C#:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace consoleblocking
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Non-blocking");
            Process.Start ("./shell-block.sh");

            Console.WriteLine ("Blocking");
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = "./shell-block.sh";
            startInfo.Arguments = "";
            using (var myProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                myProcess.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you! *thumbup*